# Uncover Table Row-wise not working with \setbeamercovered{transparent}

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,compress,
               xcolor={dvipsnames,table}
              ]{beamer}
%%%Beameroptions
 \usetheme{Luebeck}
 \usecolortheme{orchid}
 \usefonttheme{default}
 \useinnertheme{rectangles}
 \useoutertheme{default}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{onslide}
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
\hline 
letter  & number & misc. \\
\hline
\onslide<1->{
A & 10 & ! \\
}
\onslide<2>{
B & 20 & ? \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{onslide+}
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
\hline 
letter  & number & misc. \\
\hline
\onslide+<1->{
A & 10 & ! \\
}
\onslide+<2>{
B & 20 & ? \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{onslide in every cell}
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
\hline 
letter  & number & misc. \\
\hline
\onslide<1->{A} & \onslide<1->{10} & \onslide<1->{!} \\
\onslide<2->{B} & \onslide<2->{20} & \onslide<2->{?} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{pause}
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
\hline 
letter  & number & misc. \\
\hline
A & 10 & ! \pause\\
B & 20 & ? \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I want to do is uncover a similar table in two steps. Unfortunately I face some problems with that. I have already read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83675/table-overlay-in-beamer-on-multiple-rows) and it does work fantastically. ([I also followed these descriptions.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139094/beamer-uncover-overlay-pause-not-working))However, once I add `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` to the preamble it does not work anymore.

Instead of using the whole argument enclosed in `\onslide<2->{ ... }` only the contents of the first cell is displayed in transparent. I found a workaround [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113033/interference-between-onslide-and-setbeamercoveredtransparent), using `\onslide+<2->{ ... }`,which works fine, but not in the way I would like it to behave: Instead of displaying the argument transparent it is not displayed at all. I could live with this for the moment, but as `itemize` environments work just fine I would rather switch off transparency entirely. (`\visible<2->{ ... }` has the same effect. Using `\invisible{ ... }` is more complicated and has similar effects.)

Another problem arises with the alignment of the first column, but this might just be unfortunate and removed  by commenting out line endings. I have not tried this yet because I wanted to focus on the other problem.

I also tried to workaround with putting `\onslide<2->{ ... }` in every cell, which works 'just' fine, but is a rather nasty workaround. While the example shows a very small table, the actual ones are much more complicated and I would prefer a simpler solution.

I have also tried the pause command, which produces two slides, that are exactly the same. Again if I remove the `transparent` option it works just fine (as it should).

I expect the problem to be similar to that described in section 23.4 with the alignment in formulas (the code is reprocessed several times, messing things up.). But I have no clue of the internals, hence cannot create a working solution. For that kind of thing was suggested a workaround, which is even more nasty than putting `onslide` in every cell. ([See here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35970/transparency-does-not-work-correctly-with-alignment))

I browsed manual and the internet quite a bit but nothing led me to a satisfying conclusion. (Apart from those I already discussed.) Maybe someone can point me in the right direction. I am interested in some more convenient and more elegant solutions than the presented ones. Any ideas are very welcome.

Comment: It is a grouping problem related to the way `\opaqueness` is implemented.  Unfortunately I don't see a simple work around.  Your misalignment problem is simply an end of line outside of the `\onslide`s that is needs to be commented out.

Comment: @andrewswann I was afraid that this would happen. I have done some research and unfortunately came back with no solution whatsoever. I recently run into a similar problem with `\alert<>{}`, which does not compile at all. So this is really a colour related issue. At least i got the tumbleweed for this question. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try updating. The following works fine in `pdflatex` from `TeXlive 2016`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,compress,
               xcolor={dvipsnames,table}
              ]{beamer}

\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{default}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useoutertheme{default}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{pause}
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
\hline 
letter  & number & misc. \\
\hline
A & 10 & ! \pause\\
B & 20 & ? \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Since I have adjusted my presentation style to be different, I completely forgot. Do you have any idea about *why* it does work now?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Maybe some changes in beamer?